# Correct Format in Passing Dynamic Text in JSON String for Excel Headers

Tags: json, reactjs, excel

I have a variable that translates dynamically based on the selected language of the user. I am trying to replace the text for the column headers of the excel file being downloaded but I cannot get the correct format where in I can replace the hardcoded headers text with my variable. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Here's the return inside  my json to excel function

```
    var newJson = this.props.users_list.map(function (obj) {
          return {
                "Name": /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.name) ? "\'" + obj.name : obj.name,
                "Contact": /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.contact) ? "\'" + obj.contact : obj.contact,
                ....
                }
}
```

I want to replace the headers "Name" and "Contact" here with the variable lang.name and lang.contact which are declared like this after my imports:

```
const toolLanguage = {
    name: "Name",
    contact: "Contact"
};
const lang = Utilities.translateLang(toolLanguage);
```

I've tried these formats but I'm only getting typing errors:

```
    lang.name : /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.name) ? "\'" + obj.name : obj.name,
    lang.contact : /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.contact) ? "\'" + obj.contact : obj.contact,
```

```
    {lang.name} : /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.name) ? "\'" + obj.name : obj.name,
    {lang.contact} : /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.contact) ? "\'" + obj.contact : obj.contact,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format works for me:

```
  var newJson = this.props.users_list.map(function (obj) {
               let objTemp = {};
               objTemp[lang.name] = /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.name) ? "\'" + obj.name : obj.name,
               objTemp[lang.contact] = /^[-@=+]/.test(obj.contact) ? "\'" + obj.contact : obj.contact
      return objTemp;
            });
```